# Can anyone tell me where to get Vim 7.2 with cscope support?

Tags: vim, cscope

I wanted to use cscope enabled vim - unfortuantely , the binaries at work are not compiled with cscope support , and when I tried building from src , I'm getting a lot of errors due to proper dev packages not being installed.

So , does anyone have a link where I can a precompiled binary with cscope support ? Btw , I'm using linux.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what distro you're using. And whether or not you have privileges to install "proper dev packages" on your work box.

Comment: Umm..can you tell me how to find that out ? I just have a linux account which I use through putty - is there a command which can tell me which distro / what version ?

Comment: `cat /etc/lsb-release` should tell you.

Comment: `LSB_VERSION="1.3"`
Does that help for answering my question ? I couldn't make anything out of the command's output :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite an answer to your request for a pre-compiled vim 7.2, but you said part of your compiling problems is that you "don't have the privileges for installing reqd packages" (in you comment to @chenkaie's answer).  If the other reqd packages use `configure`, you can compile them to install into a directory you have control over, like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/dir/with/permissions
make && make install
```

`configure`-based installers support the `--prefix` switch, which results in the installed packages in locations like `<prefix>\bin`, `<prefix>/lib`, etc.  With this trick you may be able to build all the reqd packages in order to build vim 7.2 itself.

If the reqd packages are not `configure`-based, you might want to look at the installer (makefile?) of the reqd package to see if it has an option similar to `configure --prefix=<dir>`

Answer (score 5):

Just build your own vim binary from source code maybe a good solution ^_^

```
wget ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/unix/vim-7.2.tar.bz2
tar xjf vim-7.2.tar.bz2
cd vim72
./configure --enable-cscope
make && make install
```

You will get a cscope supported vim 7.2

Comment: Tried that before posting query - getting loads of error !! I don't have the privileges for installing reqd. packages , hence the query!

Answer (score 0):

I have the default package Ubuntu gives me from doing an 'apt-get install vim', vim_1%3a7.1-138+1ubuntu3.1_i386.deb.

Inside of vim, when I type

```
:echo has('cscope')
```

it prints

```
1
```

as expected.

Granted, you do say you are looking for Vim 7.2  I don't know what improvements 7.2 has seen over 7.1, but [it looks like there are still build problems with 7.2 that are being hammered out](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8439582#post8439582).  I'd suggest just using 7.1 for the time being.

Comment: Yeah , but I don't have Ubuntu at work - will it work if I just copy the binary from Ubuntu's /usr/bin to my work account ?

Comment: Probably not.  Could you state what distribution you *are* using at work?

Comment: I faced lots of problems with 7.0/7.1 ver. Some of quite popular plugins work only on 7.2+ - I think that is why author is asking about this particular version.